# How to test methods in application controller? My approach makes other tests randomly crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a simple method in the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def filename_for_export(project, type, format = nil)
    buffer = "#{project.customer} - #{project.name} (#{type}, #{t 'org.name'}, #{Date.today.to_s :db})"
    buffer += ".#{format}" if format
    buffer
  end
end
```

I have the following test for it:

```
describe ApplicationController do
  describe '#filename_for_export' do
    before { @controller = ApplicationController.new }

    it 'returns a good human readable filename' do
      project = create(:project)
      result = @controller.instance_eval{ filename_for_export(project, 'Audit') }
      expect(result).to eq 'Project test customer - Project test name (Audit, Access for all, 2015-06-15)'
    end
  end
end
```

Everything works fine. Then I added another test:

```
it 'appends a format extension if given' do
  project = create(:project)
  result = @controller.instance_eval{ filename_for_export(project, 'Audit', 'pdf') }
  expect(result).to eq 'Project test customer - Project test name (Audit, Access for all, 2015-06-15).pdf'
end
```

Also working fine. But interestingly, this 2nd test seems to break something which makes many other specs fail randomly:

```
...
rspec ./spec/features/file_upload_spec.rb:18 # File upload displays a preview of an uploaded file
rspec ./spec/features/file_upload_spec.rb:4 # File upload allows to upload a file
rspec ./spec/features/file_upload_spec.rb:27 # File upload displays a preview of an uploaded file (from the temporary cache) after a re-display of the form
rspec ./spec/features/file_upload_spec.rb:60 # File upload allows to remove a file
rspec ./spec/features/markdown_spec.rb:4 # Markdown uses Pandoc as converter for inline markdown
rspec ./spec/features/users/destroy_spec.rb:22 # Deleting user signed in as admin grants permission to delete other user
rspec ./spec/features/success_criteria/show_spec.rb:6 # Showing success criterion displays a success criterion
rspec ./spec/features/boilerplate_originals/edit_spec.rb:11 # Editing boilerplate grants permission to edit a boilerplate
...
```

It's always another set of specs that fail (I guess it's some order issue), but I have no idea what could be breaking things? This 2nd spec doesn't do anything different than the 1st one, so what could it break?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what causes the failures but what I can tell you that it almost always is a horrible idea to mess with `ApplicationController` in specs. I suspect that it has some sort of singleton aspect to it, but not sure. What I would do is put that method into a helper or plain Ruby class. It will save you a lot of headaches. Also, hands off `instance_eval`, no bueno as well.

Comment: Why are you using instance_eval? Just call the method. Unrelated, but I thought `let` was preferred over instance vals these days.

Comment: Thanks guys. I extracted the method into a helper and `include` it in every controller I need. This way I can write a simple helper spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do this you can use Rspec's anonymous controller as described [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-13/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller)

```
 ...

 controller do
   def index
     project = create(:project)
     render json: filename_for_export(project, 'Audit', 'pdf')
   end
 end

 it 'appends a format extension if given' do
   get :index
   expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq 'Project test customer - Project test name (Audit, Access for all, 2015-06-15).pdf'
 end
```

However, I would strongly recommend that you simply extract this method into a plain old ruby object and test that in isolation as unit test. The request specs your write for your 'regular' controller methods should cover the integration.

Comment: Thanks. I extracted the method into a helper and `include` it in every controller I need. This way I can write a simple helper spec.

Comment: Ok, then you can even extract it into a shared behavior.